# How to perform SQL injection attack on this code?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection, database-security

In a local xampp server which I set up for development, I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `entries`
(

`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

`entry` text NOT NULL,

`date_entered` datetime NOT NULL

)
```

In order to learn how to secure my queries against SQL injections, I want to induce one (I am intentionally not using prepared statements). I have a query to insert an entry in this table like so:

```
$sql = 'insert into entries ( title , entry , date_entered ) '
    . 'values("'
    . $postTitle
    . '","'
    . $postEntry
    . '","'
    . $dateEntered
    . '")';
```

It works (it does insert entries in the table), but I failed to induce SQL injection attack against it. Here is what I tried to insert in the `$postEntry` field:

```
;drop table entries;
;drop table entries;'
';drop table entries;'
`;drop table entries;'
q';drop table entries;
q","e");drop table entries; --'
q","e");drop table entries;--
```

For the last value the SQL query became:

```
insert into entries ( title , entry , date_entered ) values("r","q","e");drop table entries;--","2016-08-18 10:35:36")
```

Still the entries table intact!

I modified the SQL string to use single quotes like so:

```
$sql = 'insert into entries ( title , entry , date_entered ) '
    . ' values(\''
    . $postTitle
    . '\',\''
    . $postEntry
    . '\',\''
    . $dateEntered
    . '\')';
```

Then tried:

```
q','2016-5-5');drop table entries; --'
```

But still no luck! How should I produce SQL injection attack then?
note : the proposed duplicate is not duplicate and not even an answer . the whole point of this question is to demo the expoite so that i make sure the security measures are working.

Comment: Try a sub-query instead of multiple comma seperated.

Comment: mysqli_multi_query(); to execute multiple query separated by semi (;) colon

Comment: In order to learn how to secure your queries against SQL injections, you have to learn how to secure your queries. While whatever injection stuff is totally irrelevant to protection.

Comment: @Your-Common-Sense : in order to make sure that i am in the right direction i need to demonstrate that the -previously - exploitable code is now safe !! that is the point of the question . it is sad that some people does not get that.

Comment: @Your-Common-Sense downvoted and labeled this question duplicate in order to promote his own question.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not allow multiple statements in one Query. That is why the Drop statements are ignored.

Use `mysqli_multi_query()` for multiple queries.

You could still use other injections here.

Try using

> http://sqlmap.org/

to check the vulnerability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably insert more than a single value and spam the table but like someone said, you can't run multiple statements in a single query.

So for example, you could span the table by appending masses of additional submissions from a single post. You will need to work on this but at a guess you could try setting $postEntry to be:

```
poo'),'2016-5-6'),('poo','poooo','2016-5-5'),('poo','poooo
```

The idea being that the start of the $postEntry string first ends the original query correctly, then appends additional values and then ends at the point the original query was going to enclose a single quote around the value of $postEntry.  You would need to set $postEntry to be exactly what I've typed.. I think.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't going to add anymore to my answer as I didn't want you to think I was a hacker :| but I guess to help you understand how a hacker might abuse your code I can show you another way.

For example, let's say I wanted to understand more about the system and how I could (potentially) reveal passwords, card data etc plus we are assuming I'd already found a weak point like the one you've created.

The basic premise is that I've found a weakpoint in a blog post screen and anything I post is a post I own or can see on the website after posting.

As a result, I can pretty much use the postEntry field as an output for showing the result of any SQL queries by manipulating the value of postTitle.

*NOTE: I may have missed a single quote or something somewhere because I'm just typing this on the fly based on what I know could work so you'd need to mess with the theory slightly. I'm pretty sure though my code example could be copied and pasted.*

**Step 1). Reveal a list of the tables available to query.**
Set $postTitle (not entry) as follows:

```
poo',SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEME.TABLES),'2016-5-5'),'poo
```

After submitting that (and assuming you are taking me to a page showing me my post) the main post area should contain a comma separated list of tables from the database

**Step 2). Clean up**
Copy the list and instantly delete my post to decrease the alert status for anyone watching.

**Step 3). Get table column names**
Use exactly the same method to create a SELECT statement that fetches all COLUMN names from a specific table of which the names I now know. I get a post that contains a comma separate list of columns for that table.

**Step 4). Clean up again**

**Step 5). You can probably see where this is heading now**
So now I can pretty much select any data I want from any table  by running a select statement and viewing the output on my post.